# Similarity of two rotation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

By using change of basis formula, prove that for any $\theta
  \in \mathbb R$, $M$ and $M'$ are similar/conjugate, where 
  $
   M\,=\,
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \text{cos} \theta & -\text{sin} \theta \\      \text{sin} \theta  & \text{cos} \theta \\      \end{array} } \right] 
   $ and 
   $M'\,=\,
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   e^{i\theta} & 0  \\      0  & e^{-i \theta} \\
 \end{array} } \right]. $

Here is my attempt:

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$.
Consider the linear transformation given by
$$T_\theta: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$$
with respect to $B$ and defined by
$$T_\theta(e_1)=(cos~\theta, ~sin~ \theta)=cos~\theta.e_1+sin~\theta.e_2$$
and
$$T_\theta(e_2)=(-sin~\theta, ~cos~ \theta)=-sin~\theta.e_1+cos~\theta.e_2$$
Then  $[T_\theta]_B^B\,=\,
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \text{cos} \theta & -\text{sin} \theta \\      \text{sin} \theta  & \text{cos} \theta \\      \end{array} } \right] 
   $.

Consider $\alpha_1=(1,-i)~ \text{ and } \alpha_2=(-1,-i)$. One can prove that 
   $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ forms a basis. Let
   $$T_\theta(\alpha_1)=T_\theta((1,-i))=T_\theta(e_1-ie_2)=
    \left(\begin{array}{c}
               cos~\theta +isin~\theta \\
               sin~\theta-icos~\theta 
                \end{array}
\right) =(cos~\theta+isin~\theta) \left( \begin{array}{c}
                                          1\\ -i
                                         \end{array} \right)
  $$
  Similarly, 
  $$T_\theta(\alpha_2)=(cos~\theta-isin~\theta).\left( \begin{array}{c}
                                          -1\\ -i
                                         \end{array} \right)$$
  Hence $[T_\theta]_{B'}=\,
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   e^{i\theta} & 0  \\      0  & e^{-i \theta} \\
 \end{array} } \right].$

So $M$ and $M'$ are matrix respectively of the same linear transformation with respect to 
 $B$ and $B'$. Hence $M$ and $M'$ are similar.

I would like to know whether the above calculation is correct or not.

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors?